# Elasticsearch 5 Suggester for Products/title

Tags: elasticsearch, autosuggest

since weeks i am searching the best way to do a suggester/completer for my products.
I found some nice tutorials like: https://www.elastic.co/blog/you-complete-me
but no one could help me.

I have some products in my Index with titles. 
For example:
"Apple iPhone 5s, 32GB",
"Apple iPad Pro, 9.7, 32GB"
"Sony xPeria, Handy"
"Google Pixel, Handy"

So my Problem now is the search=>suggest i want to get:

"a" => "apple"

"pix" => "pixel"

"apple i" => "apple iphone, apple ipad"

"handy g" => "handy google"

"handi" => "handy"

"apple ifone" => "apple iphone"

Is there a way to get this problem solved with the current suggesters? And if yes, how could i solve this?

Thanks in advance!!!